# General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column of type INT

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an int column in my database and I update it according to the user selection of a dropdown menu in my html\php code:

```
<select name="regularClass">
  <option value=NULL selected>None</option>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT idClass FROM Class WHERE category='ET'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row_count = $result->rowCount();
if ($row_count > 0){
while ($row = $result->fetch())
  {
    echo "<option value=".$row['idClass'].">".$row['idClass']."</option>";
  }
}
?>
</select><br><br>
Transportaion:
<input type="radio" name="transportation" value="BUS" checked>Bus</option><br>
<input type="radio" name="transportation" value="KHAS">Khas</option><br>
Bus:
<select id="busDropdown" name="bus">
    <option value=NULL selected>None</option>
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT busNumber FROM Bus";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row_count = $result->rowCount();
    if ($row_count > 0){
    while ($row = $result->fetch())
      {
        echo "<option value=".$row['busNumber'].">".$row['busNumber']."</option>";
      }
    }
    ?>
    </select><br><br>
```

Where I need the user to select a bus number or 'None' if there is none. The problem that I get an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column 'Bus_busNumber' at row 1

The error is thrown fro the following lines:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['save']))
  {

  try{
  $ssn = $_POST['ssn'];
  } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException $e) {
        System.out.println("Student already registered");
    }
  $fullName = $_POST['fullName'];
  $transportation = $_POST['transportation'];
  $qualification = $_POST['qualification'];
  $neighborhood = $_POST['neighborhood'];
  $dob = $_POST['dob'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $bus = $_POST['bus'] ;
  $grade = $_POST['grade'];
  $notes = $_POST['notes'];
  $nationality = $_POST['nationality'];
  $regularClass = (int)$_POST['regularClass'];
  $mobileNumber = $_POST['mobile'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];

  $stmt= $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Student (ssn, name, transportation, qualification, neighborhood, dob, email, Bus_busNumber, grade,note, nationality, Class_idClass, mobile, phone)
    VALUES (:ssn,:fullName,:transportation,:qualification,:neighborhood,:dob,:email,:bus,:grade,:notes,:nationality,:regularClass,:mobileNumber,:phone)
                                ");
  $stmt->bindParam(':ssn',$ssn);
  $stmt->bindParam(':fullName',$fullName);
  $stmt->bindParam(':transportation',$transportation);
  $stmt->bindParam(':qualification',$qualification);
  $stmt->bindParam(':neighborhood',$neighborhood);
  $stmt->bindParam(':dob',$dob);
  $stmt->bindParam(':email',$email);
  $stmt->bindParam(':bus',$bus);
  $stmt->bindParam(':grade',$grade);
  $stmt->bindParam(':notes',$notes);
  $stmt->bindParam(':nationality',$nationality);
  $stmt->bindParam(':regularClass',$regularClass);
  $stmt->bindParam(':mobileNumber',$mobileNumber);
  $stmt->bindParam(':phone',$phone);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->CloseCursor();
  exit;
}
?>
```

i understand that this error comes from the null value which is the default value for this column!
I do not want to change the strict mode (the solution I found after reading many posts) I need to solve this instead.
Please help me to solve this..

Comment: Do you allow NULL on the column? The code you have presented has nothing to do with the error.. The error relates to an insert/update. If you use `$_POST['regularClass']` that value is a string, not `NULL`. You should add the code that is inserting/updating.

Comment: What does the code shown have to do with any column called `Bus_busNumber`?  Which line of this code is throwing this error?

Comment: @user3783243 yes its the default value for that column, I have updated my code, Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: @David you are right, I have added all the related parts.

Comment: `for column 'Bus_busNumber'` yet your column select shows `busNumber`.

Comment: @Sosy: The linked duplicate has examples for passing a `NULL` value to a PDO query.  Essentially what's happening is you're passing the value as-is from the HTML form, and when no "bus" is selected that value is the *string* `"NULL"`.

Comment: @David How can I solve that? I mean 'NULL' is just null, what type should I cast the string null into?

Comment: @Sosy: You would conditionally check if the value is an integer.  If it is, use it for the query parameter.  If it isn't, bind a `null` parameter.  `null` and the *string* `"null"` are not the same thing.

Comment: @David I'll try this, Thank you very much!

Comment: @David it worked! Thank you very much! I hope you would add your comment as an answer.